# Vim: My custom colorscheme's colors are applied but colorscheme name still shows up as default

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have this weird problem in my setup. I have my own colorscheme `myown.vim`. When I open files, the colors are applied properly, but if I do `:colorscheme` it shows `default` instead of `myown`.

Here's my entire `.vimrc` file - https://github.com/ronakg/my-dot-files/blob/master/vimrc

I'm using iTerm2 on OS X Yosemite. Have this problem on both local files and remote files on a Linux host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized that I needed to have `let g:colors_name="myown"` in my colorscheme file.